# Why is sublime text showing git commit information?

Tags: git

I am using sublime text 2 to look at a file in a git repo. The file is showing git information like this after I did a `git stash; git revert C44sdf...`

[image]

Why is it showing this? How do I fix it?

Comment: There was a merge conflict; this is the typical view you see in that case.

Comment: You have a git merge conflict that you need to resolve.  This isn't related to sublime, as git will add the merge conflict markers to the files themselves for you to easily find and address in any editor before committing the changes with git.

Comment: These are always the things that make me super mad when using a visual repository tool screw a conflict up. From that point I learned and always use the command line, lol :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an indication that a conflict occurred. Normally, developers resolve the conflicts between the conflict markers `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>`, and commit the resolved code.

Since you say that you are looking at a file in a Git repository, it sounds like the conflict was not completely resolved but the file was committed. It would be a good idea to track down the source of this conflict and to ensure that it gets properly resolved.

The `git blame <filename>` command will probably be helpful here. It gives output like

```
abcd123 (User name YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TZ 1) First line of the file
1234abc (User name YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TZ 2) Second line of the file
abcd123 (User name YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TZ 3) Third line of the file
```

You can locate the commit that introduced the conflict by inspecting the first column of this output on the affected lines.

Once you have located the source of the problem, somebody will need to properly resolve the conflict, `add` the modified file(s), and `commit` them. A message like `Fix conflict missed in commit 1234abc` will probably be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That file has a merge conflict. Try `git reset --hard [commit-hash]` to discard all changes in your files and set the files to `[commit-hash]`